# is tomcat 9.0.7 a Genuine version?

Tags: tomcat, system, server-administration, tomcat9

I want to make sure is Tomcat 9.0.7 a Genuine version or no?

I have downloaded 9.0.7 from the below link 
https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.7/bin/

Comment: any tomcat version you download from the official website of tomcat should adhere to some version of java ee specification

Comment: @Bharath: so is this an official site for tomcat https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.7/bin/  ?

Comment: you can download from here too: https://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.10/